# Removing background of a transparent image in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am simply displaying an `Image` on my `Xamarin Forms` page. The image is transparent and this is how it displaying on page:

[image]

How can I remove those white and grey background?
This is my source code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image x:Name="myimage" Aspect="Fill">
            </Image>
        </StackLayout>
 </ContentPage.Content>
```

Code-behind

```cs
myimage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("RailwayApp.bull.jpg");
```

My try:
I tried setting `IsOpaque` property to `True/False` neither worked. Also declared `BackgroundColor="Transparent"` on `XAML` page but not worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can't, the background is actually not transparent - it would have to be a transparent **PNG** or **GIF** to support this. This is a JPG, so the background is **actually grey and white**.

To make this work you will first have to actually make the image transparent by converting in one of the two transparent formats (and actually remove the background) and then it should display as transparent as expected.

Comment: Thank You very much for your answer. Let me try it.

Comment: Sure thing :-) . Make sure to use something better than Paint, as it does not support transparency.

Comment: Worked!! Thank you @Martin Zikmund

Comment: Glad to hear that! Happy coding!

Comment: @MartinZikmund Can we display image from `XAML`? I tried this `<Image x:Name="myimage" Source="logo.jpg"/>`. myimage's build action is `Embededd Resource`. but it is not displaying

Comment: Yes, it is possible - I would suggest following documentation which lists all ways you can use to display images in XAML - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin

Comment: @MartinZikmund Is it necessary to place those images to Android and iOS to their respective folders? even though when build action is embedded resource.

Comment: No, it should not be necessary if embedded resources are used, if it does not work as in docs, please write a question, we will help :-)